# "[libseat/backend/seatd.c:70] Could not connect to socket /run/seatd.sock: no such file or directory" after updating wlroots, Sway and libseat on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, sway

I just updated my system, there were only three updates available: `wlroots`, `sway` and `libseat`.

I don't have a display manager installed and before loading Sway I'm shown this:

`[wlr] [libseat] [libseat/backend/seatd.c:70] Could not connect to socket /run/seatd.sock: no such file or directory`

I've never had such an error before.

Comment: You should add this as an answer instead of a comment, as it solves your problem. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved by adding `LIBSEAT_BACKEND=logind` to my `/etc/environment` file. I don't know if it's the correct way to fix the warning message but it worked. It seems like wlroots dropped logind dependency and rely on libseat for seat management. I learned this from a user in the Arch room on Matrix.

Comment: With https://git.sr.ht/~kennylevinsen/seatd/commit/36f54adc2c1b16943e5470af3ad85d2b4cdf480c this should no longer be an error and so the workaround should no longer be necessary with the next release

Comment: carloabelli above is right - after switching to `seatd-git` from the AUR instead of just `seatd` there's no need to add anything to the environment

Comment: This does not work for me, now I get "no logind backend"...

Comment: Is there a way to configure a seat in a script file or is it just a kind of in theory open but factualy closed IBM secret?

Comment: This was still needed on my Arch Linux with `sway-git@r7032.c32a5073-1`, `wlroots-git@0.17.0.r6002.f8e70af3-1`, otherwise it throws the error from the OP.